# Redirect from a URL to a other server

Tags: apache, redirect

I have the following question that I do not know how to solve it in the most efficient way.
I have two servers, one with Apache where I have a Wordpress instance responding for port 80, and on another server I have a Wildfly with another application listening on port 8080. The Wordpress that I have configured on the Apache server, responds to the URL http://www.somedomain.com What I'm not so clear about is how to do when a request arrives at http://www.somedomain.com/yyyy and redirects me to the Wildfly server where an application is responding to the URL : 8080 / app

How could I do it in the most effective way? Using the rewrite module in the .htaccess file or using the Apache proxy module and configuring it in the Apache virtual host? How would I have to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing a few things that are not related to each other. First of all, a redirect is something different than a proxy. Redirecting means asking the client (browser) to look at another URL. A proxy, on the other hand, retrieves the content of the other URL itself and passes it to the client. Using a proxy, the other URL remains invisible to the client.

Second, mod_rewrite is not limited to htaccess configuration. In fact it's better to configure mod_rewrite in the virtual host configuration, just as you suggested with the proxy configuration.
The htaccess is simply for users who are not allowed to mess with the server configuration itself. Configuration in the htaccess can be limited by the admin for security purposes at the cost of slowing down the server.

That said, if you are looking to map your wildfly server paths into your main server's paths, you might want to use something like this inside your main server's virtual host block:

```
<Location "/yyyy">
    ProxyPass "http://wildfly:8080/app"
</Location>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass for detailed explanations.